# Backbone.js filter collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to filter a collection by some array values. What i want to do is to return a new collection containing the matches i get. I compare an array of ints with a collection of ints. But if the comparing value is more then 10 it won't work. so the new filtered collection never gets ints over 10. only ints from 1 to 9. Why is that?

Here is the code.

```
    filter: function(f) { //f is an array containing ints, like [2,14,9,3] etc
    var filter = this.collection.filter(function(o){ 
        var accept = false;                                    
        $(f).each(function(i,val){
            if(_.indexOf(o.get('tags'), val) >-1){
                accept = true;                      
            }
        })

        return accept; 
    });

    var filtered = new PeopleCollection(filter);
    new PeopleView({
        el: this.$('.peoplelist'),
        collection: filtered
    });
}
```

Comment: If `f` is an `array` so why you try to wrap it in jQuery object: `$(f)`? What you want to achieve by this strange manner? Iterate over array elements? You can do this by Array's built-in method: [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: I want to find all matches in the 2 arrays and then create a new one (filtered) containing all matching indexes.

Comment: try console logging your comparator logic : _.indexOf(o.get('tags'), val) >-1 that's probably where you problem lies.

Comment: It is. Thing is i have run indexOf, which will not work. lets say it compares 2 and 12. then it will pick the 2 in 12 as a match. with is not. How can i solve that?

Comment: thats why it works on all items with an indez under 10.

Comment: Are you sure that the values contained in `o.get('tags')` array are of numbers? Because from your comment it seems that they are string representation of numbers.

Comment: Correct.they are string representation of numbers.

Comment: Sounds like some of the variables here are strings.  "12" vs 12.  A quick trick to convert string "12" to int 12 is to force javascript into typecasting it into an int like so:  `val|0`  (this is "value or zero", and since zero is an int, it'll type "val" to an int as well)

Comment: Hm, that dit not work either. Any other suggestions?